# Finding rotation Matrix and Translation Matrix in opencv using cvRodrigues2()

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration, rotational-matrices

I am trying to find the real world coordinates of a planar object viewed through a camera .
 I am doing camera calibration using a chessboard . I am taking around 10 snapshots of the chessboard (each snapshot different from the other ) and I am using cvCalibrateCamera2(....) function in opencv . Here one of the output that I get is the rotation_vectors which is Nx3 matrix . I have seen the documentation and it says look at cvRodrigues2() function for further details . And I have understood that cvRodrigues2() function converts the a 1x3 rotation vector to a 3x3 rotation matrix . My question is which 1x3 rotation vector out of the N , should be inputted to cvRodrigues2() function for calculating the Rotation Matrix ??

I think that each of the 10 snapshots will have different rotation vectors .Which rotation vector should I use for calculating the rotation matrix , which can be used for my original purpose of getting the world coordinates ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the extrinsic matrix represent the pose of the camera and 10 snapshots will have 10 different extrinsic matrices, then 10 snapshots have 10 different rotation vectors.

So why do we take 10 snapshots? That is because we need to make the coefficients in intrinsic matrix more precisely.When we reconstruct the 3D coordinate, we only need to calibrate 1 extrinsic matrix.